# how to do for in true section of ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, ternary

```
searchBook(inputSearch) {
    const { searchResult } = this.state;
    const { read, currentlyReading, wantToRead } = this.props;
    const mainPageBooks = [...read, ...currentlyReading, ...wantToRead];
    console.log(mainPageBooks);
    BooksAPI.search(inputSearch, 20).then((books) => {
      books.length > 0?
    (for (const book of mainPageBooks)
    { books.filter(b=>b.id===book.id).map(b=>b.shelf=book.shelf)}
    ,
        this.setState({
            searchResult: books,
            searchError: false,
          }))
     
: ( this.setState({
            searchResult: [],
            searchError: true,
          }))
      if (this.state.query === "")
        this.setState({
          searchResult: [],
        });
      return searchResult;
    });
  }
```

if you type this code that written in react.js you will find error lines under code , how i can fix it and i need to do 2 statement in the result of ternary condition when it is true.

Comment: @Garbem There's no requirement for a ternary expression to return a value.

Comment: That being said, using a straight if/else would make this code much easier.